# Iterating through arrays with given limits (python)

Tags: python, loops

I have measurements from three different elements. (tin, copper, lead)
They get evaluated differently as the have different limits.
For example i have the lead, tin and copper content in a stone mixture as my measurements and the certain limits which return different things.

```
measurement_lead = 150
measurement_tin = 1
measurement_copper = 1002
limits_lead = [0.5, 10, 50, 100]
limits_tin = [0.7, 14, 990, 11000]
limits_copper = [5, 60, 61, 98880]
```

Now i have to check if one (or more) of my measurements are above the highest limit, if yes "do something", if no i have to check if one is above the second highest and under the highest limit - and so on, until the condition if the measurement is smaller than the smallest of the limits

Hope it's any clear. Trying to write it in python :)

Edit: There are always 4 limits and the amount can't vary. These are given limits for each element. The measurements can be equal to a limit. It should always check bigger or equal to.

tried this:

```py
measurement_lead = 201
measurement_copper = 10
measurement_tin = 2008

e_mat = 2000
b_mat = 900
pw = 20
t_mat = 1
limits_lead = [t_mat, pw, b_mat, e_mat]

e_mat = 45
b_mat = 43
pw = 34
t_mat = 2
limits_copper = [t_mat, pw, b_mat, e_mat]

e_mat = 10
b_mat = 5
pw = 2
t_mat = 0.5
limits_tin = [t_mat, pw, b_mat, e_mat]

for i in limits_lead:
    if i >= e_mat:
        print("measurement is higher then e_mat")
    elif e_mat >= i >= b_mat:
        print("measurement is between e_mat and b_mat")
    elif b_mat >= i >= pw:
        print("measurement is between b_mat and pw")
    elif pw >= i >= t_mat:
        print("measurement is between pw and t_mat")
    elif t_mat >= i >= rw:
        print("measurement is between t_mat and rw")
    elif i >= rw:
        print("measurement is lower then rw")
```

Now it somehow needs to check if one measurements is higher the e_mat (with its given limits, every element has different limits), if no: if one measurements is between e_mat and b_mat and so on.

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: Could you clarify how do limits work?

Comment: thanks, i've edited my post

Answer (score 1):

Your question needs some clarification:

1. Are the limits list always in ascending order? assumption: no
2. Are there always just 4? assumption: no
3. What happens if the measurement is equal to a value in your limits? assumption: is never equal

I made some assumptions and wrote a function for you to find out which range your measurement falls in so that you can "do_something":

```
    def find_out_position(limits_element, measurement_element):
        limits_element = sorted(limits_element)
        limits_element.append(measurement_element)
        index = sorted(limits_element).index(measurement_element)
        if index == 0:
          print ("measurement is lower than lowest")
        elif index == len(limits_element)-1:
          print ("measurement is higher than highest")
        else:
          print ("measurement is between {} and {}".format(limits_element[index-1], limits_element[index+1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

I assumed it doesn't matter if all three measurements meet the limit as long as one does. If that is the case, try this:

```
    if measurement_lead >= limits_lead[3] or measurement_tin >= limits_tin[3] or measurement_copper >= limits_copper[3]:
      #do something because 1 or more meets the highest requirement
      exit

    elif measurement_lead >= limits_lead[2] or measurement_tin >= limits_tin[2] or measurement_copper >= limits_copper[2]:
      #do something because 1 or more is between the second highest and highest
      exit

    elif measurement_lead >= limits_lead[1] or measurement_tin >= limits_tin[1] or measurement_copper >= limits_copper[1]:
      #do something because 1 or more is between the third highest and second highest
      exit

    else:
      #do something because 1 or more is between the lowest and third highest
      exit
```

Idk what your do sth is but make sure you end the loop after 'doing something' so that the next elif block only executes if none of the three conditions are met in the previous block. Let me know if that makes sense. :)

Comment: Thank you, was able to solve my problem with your help!

Comment: Yay! That's great :)